# How to modify WooCommerce category navigation: Directing Subcategory Clicks to Product Listings instead of page with more Subcategories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to modify the behavior of product category links in my WooCommerce store. Currently, when users click on a product category, they see a page displaying subcategories (i.e. "Cooling and Heating" > "Air cons" & "Heaters"). However, when they click on a subcategory, they're taken to another page displaying further subcategories, if available (i.e "Cooling and Heating" > "Air cons" > "Inverter units" & "1HP units" & "Split units" and so on), instead of directly to the product listing page for that subcategory (i.e "Cooling and Heating" > "Air cons" > Page with all "Air cons" listings.

[image]

Comment: This is about settings in each subcategory *term* where you have a dropdown "Display type" with the following options: "Default" or "Products" or "Subcategories" or "Both" *("Products" and "Subcategories")* see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwiLw.png… So you need to set the desired option for each related subcategories term in Admin Products > Categories (menu item).

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Well, that was way easier than I thought it will be. Exactly what I tried to achieve. Thank you for your help.